# composer suddenly doesn't work on cmd

Tags: windows, laravel, cmd, composer-php

I was trying to install laravel after i installed composer and made sure it's working by typing composer on my cmd but right after i added this line on cmd i became unable to see composer command working

> composer global require "laravel/installer"

Now when i type composer it does nothing just like that
[image]

[image]

And here list of the current windows variables

Comment: did you install it globally?

Comment: I don't think i did this step as installed it using the .exe file do i need to do this on windows ?

Comment: If you do `echo %path%` do you see composer?

Comment: Yes .. please take a look at the last image i added now to the post listing all windows variables

Comment: Is PHP started on your machine?

Comment: Yes it is also mysql too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136164/discussion-between-yasser-moussa-and-nerdlyist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that there was 2 files composer.phar and composer.bat inside my user folder "C:\Users\Yasser" which opens on cmd by default when i removed these 2 files i was able to use the command **composer** normally thanks to [Peh](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/3219613)